# calculate the sum of shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the total(sum) of all the purchases using the "+","-" to add and remove products from the shopping cart.It should display the amount on the left top corner in front of "total:".In front of each product, the total purchase of the single purchase is displayed.

Here a [descriptive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBSZ6.png)

Here the html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="shopping-cart">
      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="title">
        Shopping Bag total : 
      </div>

      <!-- Product #1 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-1.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Common Projects</span>
          <span>Bball High</span>
          <span>White</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>

        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="549"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>

      </div>

      <!-- Product #2 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-2.png" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Maison Margiela</span>
          <span>Future Sneakers</span>
          <span>White</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="270"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Product #3 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-3.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Our Legacy</span>
          <span>Brushed Scarf</span>
          <span>Brown</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="349"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here the JS code:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      const minusButton = item.querySelector('.minus-btn');
      const plusButton = item.querySelector('.plus-btn');
      const inputField = item.querySelector('.input-btn');
      const resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn');

      minusButton.addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
        const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
        if (currentValue > 0) {
          inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
          var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
          resultField =  item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = x* inputField.value;
        } else inputField.value = 0
      });

      plusButton.addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
        const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
        if (currentValue < 100) {
        inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
       var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
       resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = x* inputField.value;
       document.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = item.querySelector('.result-btn')[0].value
+item.querySelector('.result-btn')[1].value + item.querySelector('.result-btn')[2].value
      } else inputField.value = 100
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing that you need to do.
1. You need to convert value of total price and total price to number.
2. Set the innneHTML of dev other wise you will get the error. e.g. (

`Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at HTMLButtonElement.minusProduct`)

So, in your JS

`resultField.innerHTML = item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = Number(x) * Number(inputField.value);`